# How to make consumer to switch between partitions in round robbin fashion?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I have a Kafka topic "topicX"  with 3 partitions(0,1,2) and I have 2 consumers(A,B) for "topicX".Now consumer A consumes from partition 0 and consumer B consumes from partition 1 and 2. But consumer B doesn't start consuming from partition 2 unless lag in partition 1 goes to 0. Is this behaviour of consumer configurable in such a way that consumer B switches between partitions 1 and 2 in round robbin fashion.

We had to spin up another consumer so that partition 2 is not starved for getting consumed.

Comment: Why don't you create consumerC on the node of consumer B ? It's possible to create two consumers in the same application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to change the behaviour of the consumers using the RoundRobinAssignor. However, this should be used with caution as it could also negatively affect the performance of your consumers.

To change this behaviour, you can use the RoundRobinAssignor partition assignment strategy, which will cause consumer B to switch between partitions 1 and 2 in a round-robin fashion.

To configure the partition assignment strategy, you must set the partition.assignment.strategy property on your consumer configurations. Here's an example of how you can do this in Java using the Kafka consumer client:

```
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.RoundRobinAssignor;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig;

Properties properties = new Properties();
properties.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "localhost:9092");
properties.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "your-consumer-group");
properties.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
properties.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer");
properties.put(ConsumerConfig.PARTITION_ASSIGNMENT_STRATEGY_CONFIG, RoundRobinAssignor.class.getName());

KafkaConsumer<String, String> consumer = new KafkaConsumer<>(properties);
```

Here is an interesting [article](https://medium.com/streamthoughts/understanding-kafka-partition-assignment-strategies-and-how-to-write-your-own-custom-assignor-ebeda1fc06f3) to consider when switching assignors. A related excerpt here:

> RoundRobinAssignor The RoundRobinAssignor can be used to distribute
> available partitions evenly across all members. As previously, the
> assignor will put partitions and consumers in lexicographic order
> before assigning each partitions.
>
> Example : RoundRobinAssignor Even if RoundRobin provides the advantage
> of maximizing the number of consumers used, it has one major drawback.
> Indeed, it does not attempt to reduce partition movements when the
> number of consumers changes (i.e. when a rebalance occurs).
>
> To illustrate this behaviour, let’s remove the consumer 2 from the
> group. In this scenario, topic-partition B-1 is revoked from C1 to be
> re-assigned to C3. Conversely topic-partition B-0 is revoked from C3
> to be re-assigned to C1.
>
> Example : RoundRobinAssignor with reassignment For example, if a
> consumer initializes internal caches, opens resources or connections
> during partition assignment, this unnecessary partition movement can
> have an impact on consumer performance.

Comment: The referenced article explains how to change the partition assignment strategy. This influences how partitions are assigned to consumers. I do not see anything about how it changes the order in which partitions are consumed by one consumer.